# Difference in Go between allocating memory by new(Type) and &Type{}

Tags: go

Consider the following example:

```
type House struct{}

func main() {
    house1 := new(House)
    house2 := &House{}
    fmt.Printf("%T | %T\n", house1, house2)
}
```

Output: `*main.House | *main.House`

Both assignments produce a pointer to type `House` (from package main).

From the go docu of `new`:

```
// The new built-in function allocates memory. The first argument is a type,
// not a value, and the value returned is a pointer to a newly
// allocated zero value of that type.
```

Is memory allocation in both assignments technically the same? Is there a best practice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is memory allocation in both assignments technically the same?

I'm not going to talk about implementation details, since those may or may not change.

From the point of view of the language specifications, there is a difference.

Allocating with `new(T)` follows the rules of [allocation](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Allocation) (my own note in [italics]):

> The built-in function `new` takes a type `T`, allocates storage for a variable of that type at run time, and returns a value of type `*T` pointing to it. The variable is initialized as described in the section on initial values. [*its zero value*]

Allocating with a composite literal as `&T{}` follows the rules of [composite literals](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Composite_literals) and [addressing](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Address_operators):

> Composite literals construct values for structs, arrays, slices, and maps and **create a new value** each time they are evaluated.

> Taking the address of a composite literal generates a pointer to a unique variable **initialized with the literal's value**.

So both `new(T)` and `&T{}` allocate storage and yield values of type `*T`. However:

- `new(T)` accepts any type, including predeclared identifiers as `int` and `bool`, which may come in handy if you just need to initialize such vars with a one-liner:

```
n := new(int) // n is type *int and points to 0
b := new(bool) // b is type *bool and points to false
```

- `new` ([quoting Effective Go](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go#allocation_new)) "does not initialize<sup>1</sup> that memory, **it only zeros it**". I.e. the memory location will have the type's zero value.
- composite literals can be used only for structs, arrays, slices and maps
- composite literals can construct non-zero values by explicitly initializing struct fields or array/slice/map items

Bottom line: as Effective Go points out (same paragraph as above):

> if a composite literal contains no fields at all, it creates a zero value for the type. **The expressions `new(T)` and `&T{}` are equivalent.**

---

[1]: there's an inconsistency in the use of the term "initialization" in the specs and Effective Go. The take-away is that with `new` you can only yield a zero-value, whereas a composite literal allows you to construct non-zero values. And obviously the specs are the source of truth.